# How to differentiate html elements that have same class and same structure in selenium using python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

In the image below the first 'td' is for the X quote and the second is for the 2.

[image]

I'm scraping the html website of betexplorer.com and during this scraping I have to take the quote variation of 1 X 2 element (the quote variation come out in a new DOM if you click on the quote), I have to take this in iterable mode (I did a for cycle where iterate on this Dom to take all the inside it) but the problem is that both X and 2 quote has the same structure in each element, same class same structure and if I try to take one element consequently theke the other, the problem is that I have to put this element in two different dictionaries.

How can I do this using selenium, xpath in python??

Comment: ah other things, I can't use xpath because I've saved  common Xpath in a variable and I'm iterating over

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you want to improve your answer please use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55929627/edit) button instead of adding a comment. [Comments](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) should be used for asking for more information or for suggesting improvements.

Comment: Position of each td element inside each tr is fixed. X is always the 6th element and 2 the 7th. 3 XPaths should work. `//tr[@class="odd" or @class="even"]/td[i]` where i goes from 5 to 7. To get all the odds with a one liner XPath, you can try : `//tr[contains(@class,"odd") or contains(@class,"even")]//span[text()[contains(.,".")]]`

Comment: thank you, I understand what you mean, I will try to use your advice and integrate to my work